# How to convert XML file with multiple tag to string in Android?

Tags: android, xml, string

How to convert XML file with multiple tag to string in Android?
How we can convert XML file to String an access the data of inner tag according to condition?

Answer (score 1):

I've given an example below. I think this guide will help you. [Link](http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/)

in your res/rw/sql.xml:

```
<sql>
<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
        _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
        firstName VARCHAR(50), 
        lastName VARCHAR(50), 
        title VARCHAR(50), 
        department VARCHAR(50), 
        managerId INTEGER, 
        city VARCHAR(50), 
        officePhone VARCHAR(30), 
        cellPhone VARCHAR(30), 
        email VARCHAR(30), 
        picture VARCHAR(200))
</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1,'Ryan','Howard','Vice President, North East', 'Management', NULL, 'Scranton','570-999-8888','570-999-8887','ryan@dundermifflin.com','howard.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(2,'Michael','Scott','Regional Manager','Management',1,'Scranton','570-888-9999','570-222-3333','michael@dundermifflin.com','scott.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(3,'Dwight','Schrute','Assistant Regional Manager','Management',2,'Scranton','570-444-4444','570-333-3333','dwight@dundermifflin.com','schrute.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(4,'Jim','Halpert','Assistant Regional Manager','Manage',2,'Scranton','570-222-2121','570-999-1212','jim@dundermifflin.com','halpert.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(5,'Pamela','Beesly','Receptionist','',2,'Scranton','570-999-5555','570-999-7474','pam@dundermifflin.com','beesly.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(6,'Angela','Martin','Senior Accountant','Accounting',2,'Scranton','570-555-9696','570-999-3232','angela@dundermifflin.com','martin.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(7,'Kevin','Malone','Accountant','Accounting',6,'Scranton','570-777-9696','570-111-2525','kmalone@dundermifflin.com','malone.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(8,'Oscar','Martinez','Accountant','Accounting',6,'Scranton','570-321-9999','570-585-3333','oscar@dundermifflin.com','martinez.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(9,'Creed','Bratton','Quality Assurance','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-222-6666','333-8585','creed@dundermifflin.com','bratton.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(10,'Andy','Bernard','Sales Director','Sales',2,'Scranton','570-555-0000','570-546-9999','andy@dundermifflin.com','bernard.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(11,'Phyllis','Lapin','Sales Representative','Sales',10,'Scranton','570-141-3333','570-888-6666','phyllis@dundermifflin.com','lapin.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(12,'Stanley','Hudson','Sales Representative','Sales',10,'Scranton','570-700-6666','570-777-6666','shudson@dundermifflin.com','hudson.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(13,'Meredith','Palmer','Supplier Relations','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-555-8888','570-777-2222','meredith@dundermifflin.com','palmer.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employee VALUES(14,'Kelly','Kapoor','Customer Service Rep.','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-123-9654','570-125-3666','kelly@dundermifflin.com','kapoor.jpg')</statement>
</sql>
```

in your helper class:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String s;
                try {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "1", 2000).show();
                        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
                        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
                        NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
                        for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                db.execSQL(s);
                        }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
                }
        }
```